# Access GitLab repo with project access token

Tags: git, authentication, gitlab

According to the documentation, it should be possible to access GitLab repos with [project access tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html):

> The username is set to project_{project_id}_bot, such as project_123_bot.

Never mind that that's a lie -- the actual user is called `project_4194_bot1` in my case; apparently they increment a number for subsequent tokens.

Either way -- and I *have* tried both with and without the trailing `1` -- I would expect

```sh
git clone "https://project_4194_bot1:$PROJECT_TOKEN@my.gitlab.host/my-group/my-project.git"
```

to succeed, same as with `my.username:$PERSONAL_TOKEN` (which works perfectly). However, I get

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for '<snip>'
```

What may be going on here? How can I access GitLab repositories using project access tokens?

---

It's not as if we'd get that far, but FWIW, the token seems to have sufficient permissions:

[image]

Comment: Workaround with SSH keys works as [documented](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/), but feels unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: Your welcome, added it! I actually have no idea where I found this solution but it was in a script of mine. This actually should be documented in the GitLab docs somewhere, but I could not find it.

Comment: @Rafael-WO I'm pretty sure I read everything on the topic. Will check again and maybe propose a change, when I find the time.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It seems that using the project name as username works. In your case replacing `project_4194_bot1` with `my-project` should work:

```bash
git clone "https://my-project:$PROJECT_TOKEN@my.gitlab.host/my-group/my-project.git"
```

**EDIT:** One can actually use any non-blank value as a username (see [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html)), as others correctly pointed out.

Comment: As written, this answer is misleading. From the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html): 
"when using HTTP Basic Authentication, use any non-blank value as a username, and the project access token as the password".

Comment: as Gavin said, I tried with any name instead of 'my-project' and it works

Comment: You can make this a bit more generic by using pre-defined variables

```
git clone https://${CI_PROJECT_NAME}:${PROJECT_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.git
```

Comment: Or even simpler `git clone https://$CI_PROJECT_NAME:$PROJECT_TOKEN@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git`

Comment: Or even simpler `git clone https://$CI_PROJECT_NAME:$PROJECT_TOKEN@$PROJECT.git`

Answer (score 10):

From the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html):

> With Git, when using HTTP Basic Authentication, use:
>
> - Any non-blank value as a username.
> - The project access token as the password.

In previous GitLab versions, it would have been necessary to use  `project_4194_bot1` as the username. However, the current version lets you use any username you wish:

```bash
git clone "https://anything:$PROJECT_TOKEN@my.gitlab.host/my-group/my-project.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that depending on the git version The 'user' can be left empty or a random string if the token is a project access token.

```
git clone "https://<$USER>:$PROJECT_TOKEN@my.gitlab.host/my-group/my-project.git"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your new answer appears to contradict the answer that worked and was accepted over a year ago. There is nothing wrong with adding a new answer to an old question (see "[I have a new answer for one (or more) old questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256207/i-have-a-new-answer-for-one-or-more-old-questions)"), but if you feel that "$TOKEN_NAME" is more correct than "my-project," then please include an explanation for the benefit of our other users. Thanks, and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I couldn't figure out how to access my repo from a client without giving it my password. The solution that worked for me was using the URL in the following format:

```
https://<token name>:<token>@gitlab.address/group/project.git
```

Note that any other format will not work.
For details, I was using argocd and attempting to continuously deploy a private repo's files. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some additional valuable information about using the token as an environment variable vs. a literal, and how to use a (literal) GitLab token inside a Python/pip requirements.txt file.

In the above answers, the syntax `$PROJECT_TOKEN` (dollar sign prefix) assumes you have an environment variable named `PROJECT_TOKEN` set to the literal token string.  If you want to use the literal token string directly in the git command, omit the dollar sign (this is "Shell 101" but it's worth mentioning):

> `git clone https://USER:LITERAL_TOKEN_STRING@my.gitlab.host/my-group/my-project.git`

...where `USER` can be anything (as noted by @rafael-wo above) and replace `LITERAL_TOKEN_STRING` with the literal project access token string.

Additional Notes...

- In general, you are encouraged to use environment variables but I'm including the syntax to use literal token strings for those who are interested...and because literal  tokens can be used with Python/pip requirements.txt files as explained next...
- You can use literal GitLab Project Access Tokens inside requirements.txt files (Python/pip).
  Note that `pip install -r` does not expand environment variables when reading from a requirements file, so you'll need to use a literal token string inside your requirements file.  If you need to use an environment variable in this situation, wrap the call to `pip install -r` inside a top-level shell  script.  Also, you need to explicitly state a name for the installed package using the `#egg` argument.  Here's an example line that works inside a requirements.txt file, using a literal token string (again, `USER` can be anything):

  > `-e git+https://USER:LITERAL_PROJECT_TOKEN@my.gitlab.host/my-group/my-project.git#egg=my_project`
- If you are using gitlab.com (not hosting your own GitLab server), then use `gitlab.com` in the above commands (instead of `my.gitlab.host`)